# Enforce strict fields.Date format with Marshmallow deserialization

Tags: python, marshmallow

I'm using Marshmallow 2.15.3 for a Flask project and want to enforce strict Date and DateTime formats. With strict I mean that I only want to accept strings that are identical to the formats below. What I'm experiencing are some difference in the handling of Date and DateTime. The formats:

```
DATE_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d'
DATETIME_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
```

For example, with DateTime I can do the following:

```
dt = fields.DateTime(format=DATETIME_FORMAT)
dt.deserialize('2018-01-01')  # fails, as desired
dt.deserialize('2018-01-01T05:06:08.012312+02:00')  # fails, as desired
dt.deserialize('2018-01-01T05:06:08')  # works, as desired and according to format
```

With Date I can do the following:

```
d = fields.Date() # does not accept format argument
d.deserialize('2018-01')  # fails, as desired
d.deserialize('2018-01-01T05:06:08.012312+02:00')  # works, NOT as desired
d.deserialize('2018-01-01')  # works, as desired and according to format
```

While DateTime does not allow extra information, Date does allow it. From my understanding there is no `format` argument for the Date field. Is there any way I can work around this for similar functionality, and enforcing my strict format both for too short and too long input values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For future-proof code I find that the `Date` class in Marshmallow 3.0.0b17 is now a subclass of `DateTime` instead of `Field`, making it inherit the `format` kwarg ([relevant commit](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/commit/8efb79a8ed45906853c53335b0ca1b36e8528208)).

For version 2.15.3 and (2.X.X in general) I'm unable to find any built in function for this. A workaround is to monkey patch the `fields.Date` class. With modifications it looks like this:

```
class Date(Field):
    """ISO8601-formatted date string.

    :param kwargs: The same keyword arguments that :class:`Field` receives.
    """
    default_error_messages = {
        'invalid': 'Not a valid date.',
        'format': '"{input}" cannot be formatted as a date.',
    }

    def __init__(self, format=None, **kwargs):
        super(Date, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.dateformat = format

    def _serialize(self, value, attr, obj):
        if value is None:
            return None
        try:
            return value.isoformat()
        except AttributeError:
            self.fail('format', input=value)
        return value

    def _deserialize(self, value, attr, data):
        """Deserialize an ISO8601-formatted date string to a
        :class:`datetime.date` object.
        """
        if not value:  # falsy values are invalid
            self.fail('invalid')
        elif self.dateformat:
            try:
                return dt.datetime.strptime(value, self.dateformat).date()
            except (TypeError, AttributeError, ValueError):
                raise self.fail('invalid')
        try:
            return utils.from_iso_date(value)
        except (AttributeError, TypeError, ValueError):
            self.fail('invalid')
```

The modifications here are the addition of the `__init__` definition and under `_deserialize` the entire `elif self.dateformat`-clause has been added. This allows me to deserialize using a submitted format, for example:

```
d = fields.Date('%Y-%m-%d') # now accepts a format
d.deserialize('2018-01-01T05:06:08.012312+02:00')  # fails, as desired
```